# How to implement fade-in and other effects using CSS

Tags: css, hover

Take for example this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/13/).

So, instead of the `<a>` tag I want to use an empty div because using `text-indent:-9999px` is not good for SEO.

To be more clear, I want to achieve something similar with this  [effect](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/041_TopPanelWithJquery/demo/index.html#) but only with css.
Take a look again on my code to see exactly my approach to achieve this effect.

Also is it possible to add a smooth fade in effect on hover only with CSS?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You need to make your question clearer with more description of what you actually want to do.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that putting a block element (in this case, a `div`) inside of an inline element (the `anchor` tag) is not good practice -- and wrong, according to standards.

Comment: @Steph, this is acceptable in HTML5: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Ah, thanks! There's no declaration in his code so I thought it useful to point out, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that using text-indent has a negative impact on SEO, unless you are  wearing a black hat anyway. http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353

Comment: +1.  And, at least for Google, Matt Cutts has said that even if something is suspect, it still requires the eye of a human to determine the intent.  Wish I could find the article on his blog that I am thinking of, as I just read it the other day.  Short answer, though, I have never noticed being penalized for text-indent, and have no reason to think that I would, either.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question (don't understand the first one), I think for browser compatibility, it's much better to use js (maybe flash) to have a fade in effect. I personally use jQuery, which makes life really easy.

Otherwise, there's the CSS3 property `transition-property` that one can use http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/.

**EDIT**

If I understand the first question correctly, to achieve the effect with the example you gave purely in CSS is hard, at least for now. You're better off using a js library like jQuery for effects like bounce and fade-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `text-indent`, you can also use `padding`.

Basically, set either the height or width (but only *one*!) of the element to zero and use a `padding-top` or `padding-left` to achieve the desired dimensions. Note that `overflow: hidden` is needed to push out all the content from view and create the "invisible" effect.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/16/

Fancier example with transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/18/

***Another*** alternative is to set a `line-height` on the hidden text that is at least twice the height of the element. But if you have a nested element with text as you do here, you will need to reset the `line-height` in that nested element. Example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/19/